# Is it possible to ignore unwanted resources in DataDog using dd-trace setTag API?

Tags: datadog

From this [article](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/guide/ignoring_apm_resources) I can see that it is possible to set `DD_APM_FILTER_TAGS_REJECT` variable to ignore unwanted resources in APM. Is it possible to do the same by setting tags using dd-trace [setTag](https://datadoghq.dev/dd-trace-js/interfaces/span.html#settag) API instead of the env variable?

Comment: The `setTag` API is for applying tags to spans, not for configuring filters. Best bet is to contact support.

From the docs: "If you can programmatically identify a set of traces that you know you don’t want to send to Datadog, and no other option in this guide solves your requirement, you can consider adding a custom span tag so you can drop the traces. Reach out to Support to discuss your use case further so Datadog can continue to expand this functionality."